# Given that $f(x)$ is a function on $\mathbb R$, s.t. $f(1) =1$, and $\forall x, f(x+5) ≥f(x) +5$, and $f(x+1) ≤f(x)+1$, what is $g (2002)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

> It is given that $f(x)$ is a function on $\Bbb R$, satisfying $f(1)=1$, and for any $x \in\Bbb R,$ $$f(x+5)≥f(x)+5,$$ and $$f(x+1)≤f(x)+1.$$ If $g(x)=f(x)+1-x$, find $g(2002)$.

How should I begin to solve this type of problem?  I just started to learn functions and this stumbled me.

Comment: So, $f=g$?.......

Comment: Is $f=g$?   And how are the conditions possible?  Can't we use the second to write $f(x+5)≤f(x+4)≤f(x+3)≤f(x+2)≤f(x+1)≤f(x)$ contrary to the first?

Comment: Sorry wait the question is incomplete

Comment: I fixed the problem

Comment: If the question is incomplete, don't post it till complete, you attract downvotes as well as lack of attention for what may actually turn out to be a good question!

Comment: I already fixed it

Comment: Hint: $f(x+5) = f((x+4) + 1) = ...$.

Comment: Is $f$ meant to be integer valued?

Comment: Post edit:  use my first comment with the corrected version of your inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Using the second inequality given,

$$f(x+5) \leq f(x+4) + 1 \leq f(x+3) + 2 \leq f(x+2) + 3 \leq f(x+1) + 4 \leq f(x) + 5. \tag{a}$$

The first inequality in combination with (a) imply that we have sharp equality in every inequality in (a). In particular we have

$$f(x + 1) = f(x) + 1 \tag{b}$$

from the last two expressions in the inequality in (a).

Using $f(1) = 1$, we can use induction to prove that $f(n) = n$ for all positive integers $n$. Assume $f(n) = n$, then, by (b)

$$f(n+1) = f(n) + 1 = n+1,$$

which would complete the proof by induction.

Then, $f(2002) = 2002$ and hence,

$$g(2002) = f(2002) + 1 - 2002 = 1.$$

Comment: Did you saw the if  $g(x)=f(x)+1-x$ part?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Minor correction, $f(x)$ is not necessarily equal to $x$. In fact, you showed that $f(x+n)=f(x)+n$. The function $f(x)=x+\sin(2\pi x)$ satisfies initial conditions.

Comment: You're right. The most we can say about $f$ is that $f(x) = x$ for $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ due to the condition $f(1) = 1$. That is, it can be proven inductively that the property $f(1) = 1$ and the assumed properties $f(2) = 2, \dots, f(n) = n$ imply $f(n+1) = n+1$. So, for integers $n$ that are greater than or equal to $1$, we have the equality $f(n) = n$.